# How to prioritize checkboxes in a userform in VBA when looping through them?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my loop that checks which boxes have true values and assigns their tag names into a string (fund1, fund2, fund3):

```
counter = 0
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            counter = counter + 1
            If counter = 1 Then
                fund1 = ctrl.Tag
            ElseIf counter = 2 Then
                fund2 = ctrl.Tag
            ElseIf counter = 3 Then
                fund3 = ctrl.Tag
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```

The code works fine however say i have 5 check boxes with tags and names a through e. I want to set an order of importance for which checkboxes get looped through first. Currently, for example:

```
fund 1 = c.tag
fund 2 = a.tag
fund 3 = b.tag
```

But I would want:

```
fund 1 = d.tag
fund 2 = b.tag
fund 3 = c.tag
```

How to I prioritize certain check boxes to be looped through first?
I tried changing the TabIndexes in each checkbox's properties and was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want to count on a `For each` loop going through objects in any particular order.

Comment: Can you just add priority info to the .Tag property - seems you are already using it. Alternatively you could rename the checkboxes including priority info in their names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could name your check boxes to reflect their priority (e.g.: "myCB1", "myCB2", etc...) and the directly get them via `Controls` collection:

```
Dim iCB As Long, counter As Long
Dim fund1 As String, fund2 As String, fund3 As String
With Me
    For iCB = 1 To 5 
        With .Controls("myCB" & iCB) 
            If .Value Then
                counter = counter + 1
                If counter = 1 Then
                    fund1 = .Tag
                ElseIf counter = 2 Then
                    fund2 = .Tag
                ElseIf counter = 3 Then
                    fund3 = .Tag
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Moreover, a `Select Case` structure could be more readable:

```
Dim iCB As Long, counter As Long
Dim fund1 As String, fund2 As String, fund3 As String
With Me
    For iCB = 1 To 5
        With .Controls("myCB" & iCB)
            If .Value Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Select Case counter
                    Case 1
                        fund1 = .Tag
                    Case 2
                        fund2 = .Tag
                    Case 3
                        fund3 = .Tag
                End Select
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Finally you could consider using an array instead of three variables:

```
Dim iCB As Long, counter As Long
Dim funds(1 To 3) As String
With Me
    For iCB = 1 To 3
        With .Controls("myCB" & iCB)
            If .Value Then
                counter = counter + 1
                funds(counter) = .Tag
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

and then access them with `funds(1)`, `funds(2)` and `funds(3)`

Comment: Thanks I went with the array!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a priority across checkboxes, I guess you already know them and you don't discover them at run-time.

In that case, just create your own collection (which you sort the way you want), declare it on top of the module (so that the variable remains global and accessible all over the execution of your program) and populate it once at initialization.

For example:

```
Public prioritizedCheckboxes As Collection '<-- on top of the form module (global variable)
'--------------------------------------------
Private Sub initializePrioritizedList()
    Set prioritizedCheckboxes = New Collection
    With prioritizedCheckboxes
        .Add d '<-- most important
        .Add c '<-- second most important
        '...
        .Add b '<-- less important
    End With
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    initializePrioritizedList '<-- initialize your list when you initialize the form (or whenever you prefer)
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------
```

... and then use your code with the priorized collection:

```
counter = 0
Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
For Each ctrl In prioritizedCheckboxes '<-- you sorted the list. So you know first you'll have d, then c, then a etc.
    If ctrl.Value = True Then
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 1 Then
            fund1 = ctrl.Tag
        ElseIf counter = 2 Then
            fund2 = ctrl.Tag
        ElseIf counter = 3 Then
            fund3 = ctrl.Tag
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```